# TF10125: The path <path> must start with $/

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I try to run TFS command:

> D:\Dev...>tf branch D:\dev\path\to\proj branch_name

and i get an error "**TF10125: The path  must start with $/**".

the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d73s8b27%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) mention that it is OK to run the command as I did, yet i get an error.

any ideas?

I run on VS 2010, TFS2010

Answer (score 0):

The guidance for the *newitem* says:

> Specifies the name of the destination file or folder or the parent
>   folder for the destination. **If newitem already exists and is a Team
>   Foundation version control server folder, Team Foundation creates the
>   branched items within it. Otherwise, newitem specifies the name of the
>   destination file or folder.** Conflicts can occur during check-in if the
>   destination already exists.

Might be better been explicit and using the following command:

```
D:\Dev...>tf branch D:\dev\path\to\proj $/MyTeamProject/branch_name
```

Comment: i cannot use this format (from several reasons; the main one is that i use maven-scm-plugin, that uses the format i wrote in my question... meaning, without the $/...